# Route audio before the speaker

Tags: android

Is it possible to route audio played with SoundPool or MediaPlayer, through a vst or some other piece of software able to process it, before sending it to the speaker?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're building and flashing your own Android ROM; yes (though that's much too large a topic to cover in a StackOverflow question). If you're writing an app; no, not as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe NO, some media players support extensions like those from Sony,you may write an extension to process audio as an in equalizer for example. So I suggest looking for the media player (not the default) api.

Comment: _"some media players support extensions like those from Sony"_. Aren't those just UI:s for the built-in effects though (the OP appears to want to add his own effect)? Sony has their own set of effects that they use for media playback (ClearAudio, VPT, xLoud, etc).

Comment: No, i believe anyone can wirte an extension for their media player have a look https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Music%20Extension&c=apps&hl=en

Comment: Does this mean that I can use that same media player embedded in my app, multiple times (in case of poliphonic audio)?

Comment: Excuse me I don't get it

Comment: I mean, if I needed to have multiple audios playing together, could I call those apis multiple times, and route their output to the main speaker, without actually making them show the UI?

Comment: You need to check the api for that, if it allows playing multiple sounds